# Чем являются выделенные слова в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

Суженого ***конем*** не объедешь и ***водой*** не обойдешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суженого (как?)конем(т.е. верхом на коне) не объедешь и(как?) водой(т.е. морем, по воде, на корабле) не обойдешь.- обстоятельство образа действия.